# How can I Fix Unrecognize command in TeXStudio 2.6 and 2.5

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

when i am using the `pdflscape` package, when i use `\begin{landscape}` this command changes color and upon placing the pointer on it, it shows unrecognized command massage and same as for 
`\multirow{4}{*}{1.}`, why it does? although it is working.

Comment: If TeXstudio doesn’t recognize the `landscape` environment even though you have `\usepackage{pdflscape}` in your preamble, try activating the `pdflscape.cwl` file under Options → Configure TeXstudio → Completion. The same applies for `\multirow` and `multirow.cwl`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

If TeXstudio doesn’t recognize the `landscape` environment even though you have

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
```

in your preamble, try activating the `pdflscape.cwl` file under “Options” → “Configure TeXstudio” → “Completion”.

The same applies for `\multirow` and `multirow.cwl`.